# Exporting a matrix in Mathematica in curly brackets format

Tags: matrices, math-software, mathematica

I am trying to export a matrix in a file using Mathematica.
I get the matrix and then use

```
Export["myfile.dat", MyMatrix, "???Format???"]
```

There are many formats. I want the one that prints the matrix in this way:

```
{{0,1,0,....},{0,0,1,...},...}
```

That is the classic Mathematica format....

How can I do this?
Which one is the correct format?

Answer (score 2):

Export["file.txt",MyMatrix,"String"] works in Mathematica 6

Answer (score 2):

In really you can do this just with `Put`:

```
a = Table[RandomInteger[], {10}, {10}];
a >> "C:\\test.txt"
```